# PHP / ajaxcall - approach to prevent abuse or direct access

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security

The problem by calling ajax (in my case through jquery) is that the target can be seen in the source of the side. I searched for a solution to prevent abuse and want to ask you what you think of my humble approach.

to know about ajax calls (correct me if i am wrong):

- you have to allow direct access to the user because it needs the access like in any regular html rendering.
- sessions can be used.
- IP tracking could be used since the user is accessing the file and not my script (this would hold for other securing approaches)

out of this i created a script which access the ajaxscript first, gets the time, hashes or encrypts the same time with a good known salt and password and delivers these two values to the user. in the success function i take this 2 values and access the main-script with the next ajaxcall. There i check these values:

1. Are the time and the encrypted time equal
2. Did not more than x seconds run after the two ajax calls

I also included a easy to fake $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' just for additional security, this can easy be spoofed and faken. Instead of delivering the 2 values through GET you could use Session to transport those :).

the index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#ajaxloadlink").click(function(){
$("#ajaxcontent").load("ajax.php",function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
    // alert(responseText);
    var pruf = responseText; // $("#ajaxcontent").html();
    var arr = pruf.split('|');
    var geturl = "ajax.php?verifyvar="+ arr[1] +"&timedone="+ arr[0];
    $("#ajaxcontent").load(geturl);

        });
    });
}); 
</script>
<button id="ajaxloadlink">Lade ajax.php mit load()</button>
```

the processfile ajax.php:

```
<?php
// the function to use for encryption
define('SALT', 'whateveryouwant'); 
function encrypt($text) 
    { 
        return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)))); 
    } 

function decrypt($text) 
    { 
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))); 
    } 


if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) )
{
    //only internal scripts can be used, fakeable

        if(empty($_GET))
        {
            $time = time();
            $verifvar_created = encrypt($time); 
            echo $time."|".$verifvar_created;
        }
        else
        {
        //zweiter Durchlauf
        $verifvar = $_GET['verifyvar'];
        $timedone = $_GET['timedone'];

            //VERIFY
            $curtime = time(); //holds also timemax
            $timemin = $curtime - 2;

            if($timedone <= $curtime && $timedone >= $timemin)
            {
                echo "COOOL";
                //now its an actual request
                $verifvar_checked = decrypt($timedone); 
                if ($verifvar == $verifvar_checked)
                {
                    echo "VERIFIED";
                    // now process the actual script
                    // :)
                }
            }
        }
} else 
    {
        echo "no direct access allowed";
    }
?>
```

It would be a honor for me to hear what you think of my approach and to correct the code if you think it has to. For me it works, i allowed 2 seconds between the ajax calls (which is easy to render since it are just 2 words).

Generally all accessible content can be accessed by using curl with correct headers by going through index.html like any regular user would. because in most environments (like php) curl can't access ajaxcalls easily since it can't "click" buttons which is needed in this script. Although in other environments like watir, selenium you can easily fake that too.

So is that for you an additional layer of security?
Thanks for your opinions helping me out. Thanks also for correcting my wrongdoings.

Have a great Day here at SOF 2012!!

Comment: This might be better on codereview, but as I see it, there already is a slight problem with your code, you can't tell how fast is a user's connection, what you might load in 1 second, another user will load in 5. So maybe you should raise the limit. Other then that, what kind of abuse are you trying to prevent?

Comment: I don't understand why You try to hide URL on client side. And I don't understand what did You mean on «curl can't access ajaxcalls easily»? Can You explain the goal of all this code?

Comment: @egor i dont hide the url on clientside, this can't be done. curl can grab the ajax-target-script and access that script directly. What curl (in php environment) can't is access the index.html and go FROM THERE to the ajax-target-script. My script needs to be called through the index.html to get the 2 needed values first.

Comment: `can't is access the index.html and go FROM THERE to the ajax-target-script` nope, it can :)

Comment: @truth i tested the script with my clients (gamers) and out of 3600 users none generated an error (i logg them). its a question of trial and error. like descriped in my post it only has to render 2 words, not a whole html site, so access is fairly fast. i would recommend though for safety (depending on your country and internet speed, i live in switzerland where internet is really fast) to increase the value. at countrary bots have more freedom. I need it to query additional form fields for a game which needs some additional security layer.

Comment: @egor i told that this is the way to access the script. it has to go through index.html! this can't be undone but adds difficulties for bots.

Comment: @Email: You didn't answer my second question, what kind of a buse are you trying to prevent? What are you trying to restrict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obfuscate things even more, you could make it two (or maybe even more) different server scripts each returning only part of the response, encrypted by a shared key which is available only from the index page. So the javascript code would have to do two different ajax calls, then put the responses together, decrypt it in client side and only then it would be usable.

But this would not help you in defense against Selenium, at it can do anything a user would normally do.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls aren't -technically- diffrent than normal POST/GET requests and the target is always has to visible to user/browser, you can't make your application secure by "security through obscurity" approach.

**If your goal is limit the request rate you should done that on web server or firewall level**. If you want to use php, you can use sessions to identify users and also limit their request rate.

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if( !isset($_SESSION['time'])
   || $_SESSION['time'] < ( time() - 60 * 5 ) 
  ){
     $_SESSION['time' ] = time();
     $_SESSION['count'] = 0 ;
   }
     $_SESSION['count']++ ;

   if(  $_SESSION['count'] > 10 ){
     die("Stop ! You can't make more than 10 requests in 5 Minutes");
   }
```

Bu since sessions use cookies, it's useless to defend your application against http flood.

Comment: @hi thx for your answer. i know it can't be secured completely.Any data/computation processed in JavaScript in the browser will be insecure since all the code runs on the local machine.  i recommended to use session to transport the values instead of GET. My script only makes it impossible to access the "ajax.php" directly without going through index.html. This is because the time gets its encrypted contreparts.

Comment: With firebug , chrome's developer tools or wireshark i can see requests that your application made. Since i have js codes of your application i can write a small php/python script and make thousand requests by visiting index.html only once.it's really easy to limit request rate with apache/nginx or iptables and it should be the way to go.

Comment: its impossible to prevent a bot who acts like a user from abusing. i wrote a script in python to abuseproof which can be done at any accessible website. i though don't get how you could request the index.html 1000x by only one site rendering. its impossible! .. since new attributes only gets rendered on new request.

Comment: Nichts ist unmöglich ;)
Actually it's possible depending on your application and user patterns. If a avarage user makes only 50req/m to one script and then someone makes 2000req you can be sure there is something wrong.

You can make any request as many as you want. If i'm limiting requests on my server using iptables and allowing only 100 req./min. per host,your 101th request will drop (since i'm dropping tcp packets there will be no http request at all).

If you watch the traffic using chrome dev. tools, you can see the headers of the request and response.It's not hard to mimic it.

Comment: Also please check : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/